# Is it possible to change a parameter name of an asmx web service without breaking clients

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

Is it possible to change a parameter name of an asmx web service without breaking clients?  For example, consider a legacy service which has a web method like so:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string HelloWorld(string NAME)
 {
      return "Hello World and " + NAME;
 }
```

The legacy service web method has the parameter NAME, but I'd like to change this to 'Name' to follow coding guide-lines.  Will this break existing clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest might be to add a new method

```
 //New clients use this Maybe you put it in a new asmx file.
 [WebMethod]
 public string Hello_World(string FullName)
 {
      return HelloWorld(FullName);
 }

//Old clients use this.
[WebMethod]
 public string HelloWorld(string NAME)
 {
      return "Hello World and " + NAME;
 }
```

WCF has ways of having a Method name and parameter be one thing, but the xml be another using annotations. I think there is a way to create a WCF service that can talk to legacy ASMX clients, I haven't tried it.  In that scenario you could rename all your methods and parameters and via attribute annotations, maintain the old names for the xml across the wire.

Comment: Am I right in saying then that this is still breaking the client as the client now has to call a new method name?

Comment: No because you don't delete your old method name. In the WCF scenario, you do change the method name and then you tell WCF to keep the SOAP message the same. WCF really bumps up the level of complexity tho. On the otherhand, WCF is a supported technology and asmx is deprecated.

Comment: Ok thanks, thats true. So what actually happens when the web service parameter name differs from that which the client expects? Under the hood, does the SOAP message not matching with the WSDL cause the remote call to fail with a HTTP500 or silently fail?